# Convert geom_point() graph into a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a bar plot showing different elements, but I am only managing to make it with dots, I'd like to have it with bars. Tried joining different individual graphs but it does not look very good.

data:

```
1 primary    wet     aver_ind/day   9.810680
2 primary    wet      aver_sp/day   7.215686
3 primary    wet aver_biomass/day 262.346116
4 primary    wet          fishers  38.762760
5 primary    dry     aver_ind/day  10.633333
6 primary    dry      aver_sp/day   7.008333
```

Joining individual graphs:

```
aver_ind.day<-ggplot(graphics, mapping = aes(x=forest, y =aver_ind.day)) + geom_col()
aver_sp.day<-ggplot(graphics, mapping = aes(x=forest, y =aver_sp.day)) + geom_col()
aver_biomass.day <-ggplot(graphics, mapping = aes(x=forest, y =aver_biomass.day )) + geom_col()
fishers<-ggplot(graphics, mapping = aes(x=forest, y =fishers)) + geom_col()
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(aver_ind.day), ggplotGrob(aver_sp.day), 
                ggplotGrob(aver_biomass.day), ggplotGrob(fishers), size = "last"))
```

This is what I'd like to reproduce in bars rather than dots:

```
index<- ggplot(graphics, aes(x= factor(season,
 level=c("wet", "dry")), y=value, size = 5,
color=season, shape=forest)) + 
  geom_point()+
  labs(
    title = "Index ",
    subtitle = "Data from 2004 to 2020")+
  
  theme( axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
         axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
         axis.text = element_text(size =20))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size =18))+
  theme()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # remove the major lines
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(x= "Forest",
       y= "Value") 

final_plot<-  deforest4 + scale_shape_discrete( labels = c("aver_ind/day ", "aver_sp/day", "aver_biomass/day ", "fishers"))+
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("aver_ind/day ", "aver_sp/day", "aver_biomass/day ", "fishers"))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=15))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8)))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=25))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  
  facet_grid(index~ forest, scales = "free")
```

[image: Ugly graph]

```
dput(graphics)
structure(list(forest = c("primary", "primary", "primary", "primary", 
"primary", "primary", "primary", "primary", "secondary", "secondary", 
"secondary", "secondary", "secondary", "secondary", "secondary", 
"secondary"), season = c("wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "dry", "dry", 
"dry", "dry", "wet", "wet", "wet", "wet", "dry", "dry", "dry", 
"dry"), index = c("aver_ind/day", "aver_sp/day", "aver_biomass/day", 
"fishers", "aver_ind/day", "aver_sp/day", "aver_biomass/day", 
"fishers", "aver_ind/day", "aver_sp/day", "aver_biomass/day", 
"fishers", "aver_ind/day", "aver_sp/day", "aver_biomass/day", 
"fishers"), value = c(9.810679612, 7.215686275, 262.3461165, 
38.76276, 10.633333, 7.008333333, 276.1975, 36.59324, 15.28125, 
6.979166667, 193.825, 32.70533, 17.07079646, 7.601769912, 202.4433628, 
35.73062)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Yes, the result is far from pretty :(

Comment: Provide output of `dput(graphics)`.

Comment: Where you have `geom_point()`, change to `geom_col()`. And change `color` to `fill`, both inside the `aes()` and in `scale_colour_discrete` to `scale_fill_discrete`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** We some tweaking:
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

graphics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = season, y=value, fill=season)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.6)+
  facet_grid(index ~ forest,  scales = "free_y")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("maroon", "gold"))+
  theme_bw()
```

**First answer:**
Do you mean something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

graphics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = season, y=value, fill=season)) +
  geom_col()+
  facet_grid(index ~ forest)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```r
# Example data
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  forest = rep(c("wet", "dry"), each = 8),
  value = sample(1:16, replace = F),
  primary = rep(c("primary", "secondary"), 8),
  type = rep(rep(c("biomass","ind","sp","fishers"), each = 2), 2)
)


# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = forest, y = value, fill = forest)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(type ~ primary) +
  ggtitle("Index")
```

[image]

Comment: You could omit `color=forest`.